# MySQL joining 2 columns with the same table

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

- **unit_cat (id_cat, slug)**: has a list of categories, example: temperature, weight, distance, area
- **unit_list (id_cat, id_unit, slug)**: has a list of units for each category, example: celsius, fahrenheit, etc
- **unit_stats (id_cat, id_unit_1, id_unit_2, date_update, hits)**: counts the times that a specific combination of unit conversion is used for stats purposes.

I need to get the cat slug, and the unit slugs for the stats table, joined with the unit_cat table and the unit_list. The problem is that I'm joining both `unit_stats.id_unit_1` and `unit_stats.id_unit_2`

Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c6e2c/2) of the structure and my current query (which is not getting the desired result):

```
SELECT
unit_stats.hits AS hits,
unit_cat.slug AS cat,
unit_list.slug AS slug_1,
unit_list.slug AS slug_2
FROM unit_stats
JOIN unit_cat ON unit_cat.id_cat = unit_stats.id_cat
JOIN unit_list ON unit_list.id_unit = unit_stats.id_unit_1 AND unit_list.id_unit = unit_stats.id_unit_2
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

The desired result should be in this format:

```
temperature, celsius, fahrenheit
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because you have conflicting conditions in your `JOIN` condition to `unit_list`. You actually need to `JOIN` to `unit_list` twice, once for each unit, to get the different slugs. Note that you also need to include the `id_cat` in the `JOIN` condition so that you don't get units from other categories.

```
SELECT
    us.hits AS hits,
    uc.slug AS cat,
    ul1.slug AS slug_1,
    ul2.slug AS slug_2
FROM unit_stats us
JOIN unit_cat uc ON uc.id_cat = us.id_cat
JOIN unit_list ul1 ON ul1.id_unit = us.id_unit_1 AND ul1.id_cat = uc.id_cat
JOIN unit_list ul2 ON ul2.id_unit = us.id_unit_2 AND ul2.id_cat = uc.id_cat
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

Output (for your demo data)

```
hits    cat             slug_1          slug_2
16      weight          kilogram        gram
6       area            square-meter    square-kilometer
4       temperature     celsius         fahrenheit
2       distance        meter           exameter
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c6e2c/4)